# Apache Digester XML roule to invoke a custom setter on a bean

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

I am trying to parse a big XML file using Apache commons-digester3.
I am interested in extract only certain data. The XML is quite complex and I would prefer not to build the whole structure but rather match the patterns I am interested in.

Say I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
    <level1>
        <level2>
            <bar>the bar</bar>
        </level2>
    </level1>
</foo>
```

And I have the following domain object that I want to parse into:

```
package my.pkg;

public class Foo {
    private String bar;

    // Note the name of the setter is not "setBar" but rather "setTheBar"
    public void setTheBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

And now I have the XML rules I am having problems to get them right:

```
<digester-rules>
    <pattern value="foo">
        <object-create-rule classname="my.pkg.Foo"/>
        <pattern value="level1/level2/bar">
            <!--What do I need to pout on here the get "the bar" value injected into my Foo instance-->
        </pattern>
    </pattern>
</digester-rules>
```

I tried all sorts of combinations of `set-method-rule`, `bean-property-setter-rule`, etc but all failed to give me what I wanted. What I want seems so basic I am sure the solution must be so obvious but I cannot get it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a call-method-rule with "usingElementBodyAsArgument='true'" should work for you:

```
<digester-rules>
  <pattern value='foo'>
  <object-create-rule classname='my.pkg.Foo'/>
    <pattern value='level1/level2/bar'>
      <call-method-rule methodname='setTheBar'
                        usingElementBodyAsArgument='true'/>
    </pattern>
  </pattern>
</digester-rules>
```

However, I'd always note that XML rules are fairly limited - they can do all the basic stuff but miss quite a lot of more advanced functionality (custom rules etc.), and if you use digester regularly you may well find yourself moving from XML rules to programmatic rules at some point. Personally, I always use the programmatic rules now, as I know I can always do everything I need.

The programmatic equivalent of the XML rules above would be:

```
RulesModule rules = new AbstractRulesModule() {
  @Override
  public void configure() {
    forPattern("foo")
        .createObject().ofType(Foo.class);
    forPattern("foo/level1/level2/bar")
        .callMethod("setTheBar")
        .withParamCount(1)
        .usingElementBodyAsArgument();
  }
};

DigesterLoader loader = DigesterLoader.newLoader(rules);
Digester digester = loader.newDigester();

Foo foo = (Foo)digester.parse(...);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Barney. It helped a lot. No I don't use the digester regularly and that is the main reason for not knowing the digester API well enough. In this case what I missed was the knowledge the method `usingElementBodyAsArgument` existed. That itself is a good reason to switch to programmatic rules.

Comment: An advantage of using XML rules would be that you do not start the pattern from root all the times. In my example above you do not have to repeat "foo" twice. But this may also be possible using the programmatic approach it may just be my limited knowledge again.

Comment: @Julian thats true, but you can always use wildcards in programmatic rules to shorten them `forPattern("*/bar")` if you want, although that may obviously alter the result depending on your source doc. But it's mainly the lack of custom rule support that stops me using them... but if you can do everything you need with them that's all good.